# How to code an app that blocks other apps from launching for a certain time using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to code an app that hinders other app from launching. Can someone please help to start from the beginning. Can someone provide an example and i'll try my best to understand it. Thanks (Full code if possible :D)

One example is AppBlock in the play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a feature that 'blocks' other apps from running like AppBlock, you simply just need to show a popup on top of the other apps.

Look into [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW), with this, you can draw on top of any other app.

Once you have that working, you should look into the other permissions of AppBlock,as it'll show you what they're doing.

AppBlock's Permissions

- **bind to an accessibility service**
- update component usage statistics
- receive data from Internet
- view network connections
- full network access
- run at startup
- **reorder running apps**
- control vibration
- prevent device from sleeping